# how to upload image in background in swift using GCD

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch

i used the following code to upload image to server in background

```
var queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0)
    dispatch_async((queue), {
        self.StartUploadProcess()//upload function
    })
```

the above code run perfectly in simulator but when i test the application on my iPad it will stop the background execution when user click home button or open other application

please help me so i can run the application even the user click on home button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of `dispatch_sync()` is to run the code in another thread *synchronously*. There is also `dispatch_async()` which runs *asynchronously*, that is, in the background.

From your question I assume you already know how to run it when you want to, just need to make it into an async call.

Comment: how i can make Async call please help me?

Comment: As I said, change your `dispatch_sync()` call to `dispatch_async()`. For more information see Apple's documentation on GCD https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_async

Comment: i made that change but when i run application in simulator it will work fine but when i tested in my ipad and user press home button the execution is stop and when user open app once again code will execute . i want my app to run till its complete

Comment: Then you need to refer to Apple's documentation on background execution at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Comment: actually i want to made dropbox like application